# Where should I put my shortcode file exactly? (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I'm making a custom plugin and trying to make a shortcode this time. So I have three files in my plugin folder.

1. functions.php
2. data.php
3. shortcodes.php

And as you can guess, add_shortcode and do_shortcode functions are inside of shortcodes.php. I'm following [this article](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/create-a-shortcode-in-wordpress) and it said to put this code

```
include('custom-shortcodes.php');
```

inside of theme's functions.php. However, My shortcode file is placed inside of my plugin so I put this code

```
<?php
    include (ABSPATH . '/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/shortcodes.php');
?>
```

inside of functions.php in themes folder to include my file but keep getting me error. I cannot save my post. 
**Am I doing the right way or am I putting it in a wrong file with wrong code?**

Comment: if its called `shortcodes.php`, then including `custom-shortcodes.php` wont work

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Oh that's just a example of the article. I'm using the bottom code 'cause the working environment is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have four .php files in your `.../wp-content/plugins/my-plugin` directory, named typically  ...

- my-plugin.php  -- the file that gets run when WordPress loads your plugin.
- functions.php -- yours
- data.php -- yours
- shortcodes.php -- yours

Then you put into your `my-plugin.php` file code like this:

```php
add_action( 'init', 'my_plugin_startup' );

function my_plugin_startup() {
    require_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'functions.php' );
    require_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'data.php' );
    require_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'shortcodes.php' );
}
```

It's this `require_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'functions.php' );`  line of code that loads your source file.

- [`__FILE__`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.magic.php) contains the pathname of the presently running php file.
- [plugin_dir_path()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/) retrieves the plugin's directory.
- you append your filename (`. 'functions.php'`) to that, and
- use [require_once](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) to load it.

There's a bunch of other stuff that needs to go into that `my-plugin.php` file, which you can read about [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/).

When you develop a plugin, you should not edit any file in your theme to load it. WordPress does that once you have activated your plugin.  You put the shortcode into your post or page to use it.

The [article you showed us](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/create-a-shortcode-in-wordpress) is accurate on how to create and use a shortcode function, but it's wrong about theme editing.

Comment: Thanks! I inserted require_once line into the plugin.php file as you said and it worked!